# strcmp in devcpp

Tags: c++, c

Почему в devcpp strcmp возвращает только 0, 1, -1 а не разницу символов в коде ascii в отличии от других компиляторов?

Comment: Потому что так ему захотелось. А почему (в каком контексте) вас это заинтересовало? Какая вам разница?

Comment: В турбо си возвращается разница символов из таблицы си.

Comment: Мало ли, что возвращается в турбо си. Возвращаться может что угодно. Главное, чтобы знак был правильный.

Comment: Это наверное не очень важно, но всё же. `Turbo C` - действительно компилятор (точнее - и IDE и компилятор). `devcpp` - это IDE, компилятор там используется MinGW (в версии под Windows)  - порт GCC под Windows

Answer (score 7):

Открываем стандарт и видим, что функция возвращает результат, **знак которого** соответствует знаку разности между первой отличающейся парой символов, рассматриваемых как `unsigned char`.

О **значении** результата ничего не говорится.

Все строго по стандарту и у одних, и у других.

Comment: Просто в турбо с она возвращает именно их разницу

Comment: Ну и что? это тоже соответствует стандарту. От того, что какой-то продавец в магазине вам лишний товар на ту же цену отвешивает :), вряд ли можно ожидать того же от других, правда? Не обвешивают - вот и хорошо :)